# Best way to load data in model, Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

Here is some information about my project:

1. I'm getting posts data user **@ngrx** store and effects.
2. Post model has `userId`.
3. When I render posts, I wan't to show `post.data` and `post.user.name`

Is there any way to eager load user data with posts?

What would be best solution for this problem?

---

This is how `post.model` looks:

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export class Post {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    user?: User;
}
```

I'm not getting whole user object with post items. I'm only getting userIds.

---

**EDIT:** This is how I fetch and render posts:

**post.effects.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class PostEffects {

    @Effect()
    posts$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(postActions.LOAD_LIST)
        .debounceTime(300)
        .startWith(new postActions.LoadListAction())
        .switchMap(() => {
            return this.postsService.all()
                .map((posts: Post[]) => new postActions.LoadListSuccessAction(posts))
                .catch(error => of(new postActions.LoadListFailAction(error)));
        });

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private postsService: PostsService
    ) { }

}
```

**posts.component.ts**

```
export class PostsComponent {

  posts$: Observable<Post[]>;
  loaded$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.posts$ = store.select(rootReducers.getPostItems);
    this.loaded$ = store.select(rootReducers.getPostLoaded);
  }

}
```

**posts.component.html**

```
<div class="content">
    <app-post-list [posts]="posts$ | async"></app-post-list>
</div>
<!-- /.content -->
```

---

**EDIT 2:** Post reducer file content

**post.reducer.ts**

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, {type, payload}: postActions.Actions): State {
    switch (type) {
        case postActions.LOAD_LIST: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                loading: true
            });
        }

        case postActions.LOAD_LIST_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                loaded: true,
                loading: false,
                items: payload,
                selectedItem: state.selectedItem
            };
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code, specifically how you try to fetch and display posts

Comment: There you go, I've edited question @BeetleJuice

Comment: Please show your reducer that handles: LoadListSuccessAction

Comment: I've added that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution but I don't think it's perfect.

1. I'm getting all users from **posts.component.ts** and inputing them into **post-list** component.
2. The inside **post-item** component I'm filtering all users with post.userId and taking one user.

I thought that would be slow, but it's not. And that way I'm making two http requests only. Posts and Users request.

For now I couldn't found better solution. If you have one, I will be happy integrating it.

---

**EDIT:**

Huh, I think I've found solution:

[Handle Multiple Angular 2 Models in ngrx with Computed Observables](http://onehungrymind.com/handle-multiple-angular-2-models-ngrx-computed-observables/),

In this article I've found code snippet, and it worked for me:

```js
export class UsersItemsService {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppStore>) { }

  getUsersItems(): Observable<UserItems[]> {
    const users$: Observable<User[]> = this.store.select('users');
    const items$: Observable<Item[]> = this.store.select('items');

    return Observable.combineLatest(users$, items$, (users, items) => {
      return users.map(user => Object.assign({}, user, {
        items: items.filter(item => item.userId === user.id)
      }));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You can find answers in this article too https://netbasal.com/querying-a-normalized-state-with-rxjs-in-angular-71ecd7ca25b4